# How can I add research notes to a reference in Jabref

Tags: jabref

How can I add research notes to a reference in Jabref (Bibtex)? This option is available in endnote but I cant find in Jabref. The research notes I write should not be added whenever I use the reference in Latex compiled document. Notes are only for me to sort out any particular information in references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JabRef 3.8.2, double-click on the entry, select the tab "Comments" and type in your research notes.
The content of the tab "Comments" will be saved to your BibTeX file, but it will not appear in your LaTeX-compiled document (unless your BibTeX style explicitly does it, which is unlikely).